# Rotation with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I’m new to java and I am trying to get PDFBOX to rotate a PDF file.. I can’t seem to get the error right.. I know it must be something simple but it says `The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Dimension` on this line:

`for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {`

And it strikes through size..

My Code:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;


public class PdfRotator {


 private static final String pdfFile = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("PDFrotatorTEST.pdf");



        //public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 List pages = (List) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

 for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
     PDPage page = (PDPage) ((java.util.List) pages).get(i);// PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
     if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
         page.setRotation(0); 
     }
 }

 File f = new File(pdfFile);// File f = new File(pdfFile);
 String newFile = f.getParent() + File.separator + "out.pdf";
 document.save(newFile);
 document.close();
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does it not compile, compile but throw an exception when run, something else? More details please, including the actual compilation errors if that's the problem, the stacktrace if it throws an exception, the actual error output if it runs but prints errors. Also, format the code better, it looks like you've got everything after the pages declaration in an unnecessary block, but it's hard to tell because of the formatting.

Comment: The line with "main" is missing, i.e. public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException , that should be below the line with pdfFile .

Comment: Doh! That must have happened when I copied it over from the other computer.. It still has an error and strikes out **size**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import the class `List` as

```
import java.awt.List;
```

But that is not the `List` you want. instead you want

```
import java.util.List;
```

---

As the OP is *new to java*, some backgrounds:

There are several classes called `List` in the java API and even more in third-party APIs. Thus, when importing a `List class`, you have to make sure you import the correct one.

In particular there are:

- `java.awt.List`, a *component presents the user with a scrolling list of text items* from the *Abstract Window Toolkit*, the oldest Java GUI API; and
- `java.util.List`, the interface for an *ordered collection (also known as a 'sequence')* from the *Java Collections Framework*.

In your code you are dealing with the result of `document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages()` which returns a list of `PDPage` instances in a `java.util.List` object.

---

The error message *The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Dimension* is due to the fact that `java.awt.List` (like `java.util.List`) has a method `size()` but this method returns a `java.awt.Dimension` (a class that *encapsulates the width and height of a component*) and not an `int`.

Thus, `i < pages.size()` tries to compare entities which are not naturally comparable.